# Set levels for OS X error dialog box

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application I've subclassed the NSWindow and set the window level as 25. While my app crashes I'm getting an error dialog box similar to this

[image]

Because my window level is 25, the error dialog is being hidden by the window.

Is there any chance to set the level of the Error dialog box.